# I am getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')" error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, filter, searchbar

I have a search bar in which I am filtering the data accordingly in ionic on key in the API is called many times. To avoid this, I have tried to filter.

**demo.html file**

```
<ion-toolbar class="ion-toolbar-searchbar">
        <ion-searchbar placeholder="Search documents" (ionChange)="onSearchDocument($event)">
        </ion-searchbar>
    </ion-toolbar>
```

**demo.ts file**

```
onSearchDocument(event: any) {
        this.items = this.search;
        const searchTerm: string = event.target.value;
        if (searchTerm !== '') {
            this.items = this.search.filter((item) => {
                return (
                    item.purpose
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1
                );
            });
        }
        this.getDocuments(this.items);
    }
```

Comment: what is the data type of search?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use ng2-search-filter. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-search-filter

Comment: the data type of search is set to any

Comment: @AnushaR Check this link "https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tfghsy?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts"

Comment: I think there is an issue with this.search. can you please put this on https://stackblitz.com/
ill solve it there